# Can not connect a Jenkins node

Tags: jenkins

An error occurs when I try to set up a Jenkins node. I am using Jenkins ver. 2.46. I am using ssh keys to authenticate the node.

Both master and node are Ubuntu 16.10, running 4.8.0-37-generic kernel and  openjdk version "1.8.0_121"

err I get:

```
[02/18/17 13:09:57] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 10.171.0.1:22.
[02/18/17 13:09:59] [SSH] Authentication successful.
[02/18/17 13:09:59] [SSH] The remote users environment is:
BASH=/bin/bash
BASHOPTS=cmdhist:complete_fullquote:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
BASH_ALIASES=()
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_CMDS=()
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING=set
BASH_LINENO=()
BASH_SOURCE=()
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="4" [1]="3" [2]="46" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu")
BASH_VERSION='4.3.46(1)-release'
DIRSTACK=()
EUID=1004
GROUPS=()
HOME=/var/jenkins
HOSTNAME=wanda
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
IFS=$' \t\n'
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LOGNAME=jenkins
MACHTYPE=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
MAIL=/var/mail/jenkins
OPTERR=1
OPTIND=1
OSTYPE=linux-gnu
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PIPESTATUS=([0]="0")
PPID=22036
PS4='+ '
PWD=/var/jenkins
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments
SHLVL=1
SSH_CLIENT='10.144.72.139 33520 22'
SSH_CONNECTION='10.144.72.139 33520 10.171.0.1 22'
TERM=dumb
UID=1004
USER=jenkins
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1004
XDG_SESSION_ID=116
_=']'
[02/18/17 13:09:59] [SSH] Checking java version of java
[02/18/17 13:10:00] [SSH] java -version returned 1.8.0_121.
[02/18/17 13:10:00] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[02/18/17 13:10:01] [SSH] Copying latest slave.jar...
[02/18/17 13:10:05] [SSH] Copied 717,563 bytes.
Expanded the channel window size to 4MB
[02/18/17 13:10:05] [SSH] Starting slave process: cd "/var/jenkins" && java  -jar slave.jar
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Slave.jar version: 3.4.1
ERROR: Unexpected error in launching an agent. This is probably a bug in Jenkins
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.launch(SSHLauncher.java:767)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:262)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
hudson.util.IOException2: Slave start aborted.
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.startSlave(SSHLauncher.java:992)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.access$400(SSHLauncher.java:139)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:738)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:719)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:147)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:821)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:520)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:390)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.startSlave(SSHLauncher.java:989)
    ... 7 more
ERROR: Connection terminated
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2624)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3099)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:853)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:73)
Slave JVM has not reported exit code. Is it still running?
[02/18/17 13:10:08] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Answer (score -2):

I've entered too small value in advanced settings:

```
Connection Timeout in Seconds
```